# Interactive courses of Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had seen a interesting course of Ruby on the Code School ([Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org)/[Rails for Zumbies](http://railsforzumbies.org)).

But I would like to know if there's another ones?

If you know someone, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking specifically for interactive courses/tutorials:

- [Ruby in Twenty Minutes](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/)
- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Comment: I already saw the Rails for Zombies. But thanks, I didn't know Ruby in Twenty Minutes, looks a good one. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, the Ruby in 20 Min is good for learning the basics of Ruby as opposed to Rails. And it's interactive bc of the built-in interactive Ruby interpreter `irb`.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://rubyonrails.org/documentation There are many references.

Comment: I wouldn't like documentation exactly but interactive courses. Anyway, thanks for help.